# tikz trees. child nodes are not showing up as expected. Where is my error?

Tags: tikz-trees

I am learning tikz tree so I can make flow chart.

In this below, I have `linear` and `seperable` children that are supposed to be children of node `degree 1` but they show up mixed with children of node `higher degree than one`.  I know I am not doing something correct. How to fix it?  Here is screen shot first

[image]

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 

\begin{document}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}, 
         level 2/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
         level 3/.style={sibling distance=5cm}} 
     
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node {ode} [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node   {first order}
       child {node  {\adjustbox{max width=2cm}{degree 1}} 
            child {node  {linear}}
            child {node  {seperable}}
       }
       %    
       child {node  {\adjustbox{max width=3cm}{higher degree than one}}
           child {node  {\adjustbox{max width=2cm}{Find roots of $p$}}}
           child {node  {solve for $y$}}
           child {node  {solve for $x$}}
       }
    }
    child  {node  {second order}} 
    child  {node  {higher order}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything is fine, the only problem is, that the `sibling distance` for `level 3` is too large while that for `level 2` is probably a bit to tight. Try `level 2/.style={sibling distance=6cm}, level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}`. I would not use `\adjustbox` inside a node, but rather decrease the font size or insert a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing really wrong in your code, you just need to adjust the styling, especially concerning the `sibling distance`s. With the set up you have, the `sibling distance` for `level 3` is too large, so the nodes from the right branch overlap the left branch creating this strange output.

You should decrease the length for `sibling distance` for `level 3` and maybe also increase the `sibling distance` for `level 2`. Furthermore, the option `node distance` is of no use in trees in this case.

Finally, I would probably not use `\adjustbox` inside a node but instead decrease the font size or insert a line break. To be able to do the latter, you can set `align=center` for the nodes. You may also want to set `text depth=0pt` to align the baselines of the nodes properly.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    level distance=2cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm}, 
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
    every node/.style={align=center, text depth=0pt}
} 
     
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node {node} [edge from parent fork down]
    child {node {first order}
       child {node {degree 1}
            child {node {linear}}
            child {node {seperable}}
       }
       %    
       child {node {higher degree \\ than one}
           child {node {Find roots \\ of $p$}}
           child {node {solve for $y$}}
           child {node {solve for $x$}}
       }
    }
    child {node {second order}} 
    child {node {higher order}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]